# 7zip - Command Line: how to set output path?

Tags: command-line, compression, archiving, 7-zip

I want to compress all HTM files in `D:\HTM\` to an archive called `comp.7z` which is created in `D:\HTM\` directory, so I do the following:

```
7z a -o "D:\HTM" comp.7z "D:\HTM"
```

and get an error, exactly as below:

```
Error:
Incorrect command line
```

Why am I getting error, *what is the correct way/syntax of using `-o` switch?*

I have tried:

```
7z a -o"D:\HTM" comp.7z "D:\HTM"
```

And:

```
7z a -o{"D:\HTM"} comp.7z "D:\HTM"
```

It creates `comp.7z` in CWD.

Comment: Please write even the error you received [editing your post](http://superuser.com/posts/903879/edit). Did you try `7z a D:\Your\full\path\com.7z D:\HTM\*.htm` ?

Comment: @Hastur, I didn't quite understand *write even the error you received*. The "`Error:\nIncorrect command line`" is what the output was.

Comment: My fault, I expected `7z` a little more _loquacious_. :-)

Comment: Always read the [manual](http://7zip.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/switches/output_dir.htm)! **-o (set Output directory) switch:** Specifies a *destination directory* where files are to be **extracted**. This switch can be used only with extraction commands (e and x).

Comment: @Karan always read the question first. Using `-o` was one of my attempts to get desired output paths. Also try `7z --help` & see the output, one of the line says `  -o{Directory}: set Output directory`.

Comment: @aim100k: I did read what you wrote, but looks like you didn't read what I wrote above. If you had taken some time to read the CHM manual that comes with the program you'd have known in a few seconds what -o does, and how it is obviously inapplicable during compression.

Comment: As aim100k said, the command line help is not so specific. It also doesn't tell you there's a .chm file anywhere, although I guess if you're the sysadmin and have some free time you might be able to find it anyway. :P  Of course, if you're that kind of sysadmin you've probably collected a backlog of thousands of pages worth of manuals that you never had time to read. "RTFM" made sense in the 70's and 80's, but this is a pretty different era.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
7z a D:\HTM\comp.7z D:\HTM\*.htm
```

You don't need the `-o` since you're creating an archive. You also fail to specify which files need to be included in the archive (`D:\HTM\*.htm`). The output is the complete name of the archive (`D:\HTM\comp.7z`). The quotes aren't needed here, since there are no spaces in the filename(s).

Comment: Great answer!  Everyone was neglecting to mention that `-o` is only for extracting!